# WPF: Slide Grid left with fade

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

What I want is for a user to click "Next" and then the current "page" of content (actually just a grid) slides left (off screen) and fades out whilst the new content slides in left from off the screen whilst fading in.

How can I achieve this as easily (and reusable) as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kevin's Bag-of-Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) has a TransitionPresenter sample with a bunch of different transitions.  It includes a wipe transition and a fade transition, but not a "wipe and fade".  You can download the source, so you should be able to combine the two transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Check [FluidKit](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/) library from Pavan Podila ([blog](http://blog.pixelingene.com/)). It has exactly what you need (`TransitionPresenter` more specifically).

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called [Transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/) (it hasn't been updated in a while) that provides packaged transitions for WPF. You can extend it to include a Wipe and Fade transition for your needs. If you wanted to build it for yourself, it's not difficult if you have Blend (animations are not something at which the Visual Studio designer excels and I wouldn't want to code them by hand).

Comment: Hey, I tried to use this but found no documentation for it! How do you use it?